# Функция: вставить meta description

Tags: php, wordpress, функции, seo

Есть сайт на WordPress. В нём таксономия `companies`, для неё в шаблоне есть отдельный `php` файл, в котором собирается темплейт. Не могу вставить в него вывод тега `meta description`. Для примера, приведу код, который служит для тега `title`

```
function page_title($title) {
    global $paged, $page;
    $sep = apply_filters( 'document_title_separator', '-' );
    if ( ! get_query_var( $this->slug ) )
        return $title;

    $company = urldecode( get_query_var( $this->slug ) );

    $title = get_bloginfo( 'name' );

    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );

    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        $title = "$title $sep $site_description";

    $title = sprintf( __( 'Услуги от исполнителя: %s', 'wp-job-manager-companies' ), $company ) . " $sep $title";

    return $title;
}
```

В итоге в `title` выводится: "Услуги от исполнителя: `название companies` - `название сайта`".

Как только не пытался, сколько бы не читал информации, не получается сделать тоже самое, только для тега `meta description`. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вы лучше покажите ваш код для `<meta name="description"...>`.

Comment: Самый простой способ - поставьте Yoast SEO.

Comment: @KAGGDesign данный плагин установлен.А самого кода для '<meta name="description"...>' нет. Я и прошу помощи его создать

Answer (score 0):

Открываете вашу таксономию для правки (показываю на примере категории товаров WooCommerce, которая как раз и есть термин таксономии products).

Вводите описание в сниппет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Открываете таксономию (категорию товара) - видите meta description

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все это работает, если вы обращаетесь к архиву таксономии как положено. Из вопроса понять нельзя, как вы выводите свою таксономию.

Comment: У меня в этом плагине нет моей таксономии. Наверное проблема в том, что это не таксономия вовсе, а просто какой то особый вывод записей относящихся к одной и той же компании. Не знаю даже куда дальше копать. Ну а этот вопрос пусть остаётся, думаю будет кому то полезен.